# How to increase the number of instance based on some input in Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I want to have a system that increases the size of my rice ball, and as the rice ball gets wider, instance more salmon piece on top of it. Right now I'm having 5 salmon piece on top of the rice ball due to the Vertex Group being used as the Selection node for the Group Input. Is there anyway to link the Value for the Transform node of the rice ball to the Instance on Points node for the salmon piece?

So for example:

- Rice ball width = 1 => 1 salmon piece
- Rice ball width = 2 => 2 salmon piece
- Rice ball width = 1.5 => 1 salmon piece

I'm having trouble in the part that the Instance on Points node will always instance a certain number of salmon pieces.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hopefully i understood your right, so you want something like this?

[image]

The input geometry in this node setup is the cube.
The map range node "recalculates" the frame (1-100) to the scale value of the cube (1-3). So at frame 1 the scale is 1, at frame 100 the scale is 3, with a linear interpolation.
I use this scale value to create a mesh line with "result" (scale value) points. So Blender "makes" out of the float an integer (Blender just cuts off the fraction). So for frame 1 i got a line with one point, for frame 100 i got a line with 3 points.
This line i also move along the z-value so that it keeps on the top of the cube. Then i instance some icospheres on that line (if you use instance on points, each point of the curve/object will get exactly one instance).

result:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's the one. Could you elaborate more on the magic you just did? I don't think I fully understand the node systems.

Comment: @Argensa *Mesh Line* is the instancer - every vertex of that geometry will create an icosphere. Here the size of the instancer is based on time elapsed in the form of the number of frames, but you could similarly base it on  *Bounding Box* node (e.g. from max subtract min, then separate XYZ and take only X to use size) or *Attribute Statistic* node.